# The proxy server is refusing connections JMeter

Tags: jmeter, load-testing

I am trying to load test for my web application. I followed all the steps as per JMeter guide. After that enable proxy server also using port number 8080.

**Please take a look my proxy server description in Firefox:**

[image: Please take a look my proxy server description in Firefox]

**Please check my JMETER Configuration**

[image: Please check my JMETER Configuration]

**Output after did all configuration**

[image: Output after did all configuration]

I am new for JMETER load testing, hope you guys will help to solve this problem.

Comment: 1. Did you start the JMeter Proxy (HTTPS Test Script Recorder)? 2. Can you check if you can connect to the machine where the proxy is connected if JMeter and browser are not on the same machine. 3. Are you using HTTP or HTTPS? 2. What's the port set in the HTTP(S) Test script recorder?

Answer (score 3):

1. Remove `localhost` and `127.0.0.1` from "No Proxy for" area in Firefox
2. Since [JMeter 3.0](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/5-key-things-you-need-know-about-jmeter-30) default port for [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder) is `8888` so you either need to switch it back to `8080` in the HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder or configure Firefox to use port `8888`. See [Bug 59006](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=59006) for details
3. You will have slightly better JMeter configuration for recording if you use ["Recording" template](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html#basic-instructions), from JMeter main menu choose `File -> Templates -> Recording` and click "Create".

   [image: JMeter Recording from Template]

Comment: It's November 2021. Using Firefox 91.3.0esr  Got same error using Jmeter 5.4.1 when Localhost use port 8888 . I did the following to resolve. 1. Accept certificate in Firefox. 2. Use Localhost port 8080. After that, I was able to use Script Recorder.

Answer (score 1):

The main problem is Firefox expects that you would have installed a trusted Certificate before listening for requests using proxy server (via your port number 8080 as quoted above). Note that this is a Trust issue. Firefox does not trust your requests.

To resolve this issue, see below steps:

1. In Jmeter, from "HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder" once you click "Start" button to start recording  and listening to requests, Jmeter creates a temporary "Root CA Certificate" in your Jmeter "bin" directory/folder automatically.

> This certificate has to be uploaded on Firefox to enable Trust.

**Note that the certificate has validity of 7 days.** See screenshot below:

[image: Jmeter Temporary Root CA Certificate]

2. Next go to your "Firefox preferences" and click "Privacy and Security" Tab, scroll down to the "Certificates" section and click "View Certificates" to upload the generated temporary CA Certificate in the previous step (step 1). See image below:

[image: View Certificates screenshot]

3. Click the "View Certificates" button to add the temporary Root CA Certificate generated above. Note that the CA Certificate is located in your Jmeter "bin" folder.

[image]
See the certificate in the bin folder below:

[image]

Upload the Certicate as seen in the screenshot below:

[image: View Certificates screen]

4. Finally, as soon as the Root CA Certificate has been added to Firefox successfully, go ahead and start recording your requests. Everything should be work without issue.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

After adding the certificate to your browser you have to hit 'Start' on the recording on jmeter before you access your website on the browser.

Answer (score 0):

For jmeter test recording, you've to follow this sequence-

1. Add jmeter test script recorder
2. Set up the proxy ( you've done till here)
3. Click start in test script recorder(you must click start only then your links(pages) will load in browser )
4. Add the certificate generated in jmeter/bin folder(you only need to do this once)
5. then you can browse using the firefox browser